# Why image with transparent background not visible in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, image, xaml, png, transparent

I have created an image to use as a ruler. It has black lines and text on a transparent background and is in PNG format. After adding it to my XAML I was surprised to find that the image was not visible, and even more surprised to find it was visible in Blend when I loaded the XAML file there.

What might cause an image to be invisible when running the application, even though it is visible in Blend at design time?

Comment: What does the XAML look like? It might have something to do with height/width settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was being stupid, which sadly happens more than I'd like. I had placed the image in the Images folder on disk but had neglected to add it to the project as a resource. Simply doing so has the image appearing, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It might have to do with the image path or reference. Can you include some XAML or source code to show how you're setting the image source?